# NFS not mounting on 11.10 upgrade

Tags: 11.10, nfs

I updated to Oneiric a few days ago and my nfs shares will not connect as they always have with Natty on this and other computers on my network.

The error message is:

```
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

So i did a clean install, copying in the fstab etc that worked on Natty on this box, but get the same error. No auto mount on boot, and when i do for example
sudo mount /nas/mydocs

Have tried -o nolock with no success

fstab has lines like this, all working before upgrade

```
192.168.6.15:/johnsstore /home/john/nas/mydocs nfs rw,auto

sudo start statd
start: Job is already running: statd
```

rpcinfo

```
   program version netid     address                service    owner
    100000    4    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
    100000    3    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
    100024    1    udp       0.0.0.0.138.56         status     114
    100024    1    tcp       0.0.0.0.228.44         status     114
    100024    1    udp6      ::.236.85              status     114
    100024    1    tcp6      ::.142.26              status     114
```

Comment: Try adding the nfsvers=3 parameter in fstab. 192.168.6.15:/johnsstore /home/john/nas/mydocs nfs rw,auto,nfsvers=3

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)